# Angular Overlapping bars using chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am trying to display a [Stack Bar Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/bar.html#general) on two datasets. The only issue is that once the graph is render the bars overlap making it difficult to distinguish between them (see example below). If the `stacked` property on the `x-axis` and `y-axis` is set to `true` the bars won't overlap anymore but they will be display in a way where bar `B` starts at the end of `A`. From the example below, how could I make bar `B` display more clearer so that it is easier to distinguish it from `A`. Maybe a property that hides pixels from bar `A` whenever `B` overlaps it.

[image]

**Component A - ComponentA.ts**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { service } from '../../..common/service';
import { ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js'

... Some Code...

@Component({
    selector: 'ComponentA',
    styleUrls: ['./ComponentA.css'],
    templateUrl: './ComponentA.html'
})

export class compA {

chartOptions: any = {
       scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: false, 
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
           }]
       }
 };

... Some Code ...

arrayOne: Array<number>;

arrayTwo: Array<number>;

barChartData: ChartDataSets [] = []; 

barChartLabels = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

constructor(private sw: Service){ }

 ... Some Code ...


 buildGraph(): void {
      this.barChartData = [
          { data: this.arrayOne, label: 'A', backgroundColor: '#fa9cb0' },
          { data: this.arrayTwo, label: 'B', backgroundColor: '#7b8dfd' }
      ]
 }

... Rest of Code ...
```

**Component A - ComponentA.html**

```
<div>
     <canvas> baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [legend]="true" <chartType>="'horizontalBar'" [options]="chartOptions" </canvas> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what issue you were facing, since you provided minimum details of your code. So, this is all I can give you as an answer, your options looks good, just the stack for x axis is `false`. This is how a sample of chart will look like or refer to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-stackoverflow?file=src/app/app.component.ts):

```js
var chartInstance = new Chart(document.getElementById("chartJSContainer"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {

    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "G"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [40, 220, 15, 16, 24, 212],
      label: "Asia",
      backgroundColor: "#7b8dfd"
    }, {
      data: [86, 114, 10, 106, 107, 111],
      label: "Africa",
      backgroundColor: "#fa9cb0"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      xAxes: {
        stacked: false //Make it true to make the overlapping bars visible.
      },
      yAxes: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.1/dist/chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but it did not solve the issue. I did explain in the problem description that setting the x axis to `true` does not provide expected behavior. If you look where the arrow is pointing in the image, I just want bar `B` which is represented by the color `blue` to be displayed on top of bar `A` so that it is easier for a user to distinguish between both bars.

Comment: Just change the ordering of `datasets[]` if you want to bring the B bar on top of A as done in the updated answer.